# Display postgresql dates on java Jtable

Tags: java, swing, postgresql

I'm facing a small issue with SQL dates and java which I already search the world on internet about this. The thing is that my program must load all the dates from a SQL table to my Java jtable. I might have to use some sort of conversion from date to string.

I tried by using conversion like this `records[0]=rs.getDate("mydate").toString();` but no luck with this.

```
private void load(String value){
    Conector cc= new Conector();
    Connection cn= cc.conexion();
    //java.util.Date date= new java.util.Date();
    //SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");                
    String [] titles={"Dates"};
    String [] records;
    records = new String[1];
    String sql="SELECT * FROM turns WHERE dates LIKE '%"+value+"%'";
    model= new DefaultTableModel(null,titles);       
    try {
        Statement st= cn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs= st.executeQuery(sql);            
        while (rs.next()) {                
            records[0]=rs.getDate("mydate").toString();
            model.addRow(records);
        }
        tablaturnos.setModel(model);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:"+e, "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Rather then changing the data to meet your requirements, create a custom TableCellRenderer which can format the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by simply collecting all the dates as `Date` objects

```
private void load(String value) {
    Conector cc = new Conector();
    Connection cn = cc.conexion();

    String[] titles = {"Dates"};
    model = new DefaultTableModel(null, titles);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM turns WHERE dates LIKE ?";

    try (PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
        st.setString(1, "%" + value + "%");
        try (ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {

            Object[] records = new Object[1];
            while (rs.next()) {
                records[0] = rs.getDate("mydate");
                model.addRow(records);
            }
            tablaturnos.setModel(model);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error:" + e, "Error Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Then use a custom `TableCellRenderer` to change the formatting to your needs, maybe something like...

```
public class DateTableCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    public static final DateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        if (value instanceof java.util.Date) {
            value = DATE_FORMAT.format(date);
        }
        return super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
    }

}
```

Then you can set up the table to use the renderer when it encounters a `Date`...

```
tablaturnos.setDefaultRenderer(java.util.Date.class, new DateTableCellRenderer());
tablaturnos.setDefaultRenderer(java.sql.Date.class, new DateTableCellRenderer());
```

Have a look at [Concepts: Editors and Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender), [Using Custom Renderers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) and [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more details

You'll probably also want to have a look at [Using Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: I was about to collect all the dates as `Date` like you said. But, can this be applied on a SQL table that is more than `Date` fields, like `Varchar` or this method is `Date` only?

Comment: Yes, In fact, you should model your data as is (or as close to the raw data as possible) and then use things like renderers formatters to display it

Comment: @MadProgrammer Assuming his database type is SQL [`DATE`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL#Data_types), shouldn't that be `value instanceof java.sql.Date` (".sql.") rather than `value instanceof java.util.Date`? And why not specify java.sql.Date throughout that code rather than Object? (sincerely asking, not criticizing, as I do not know for sure)

Comment: @BasilBourque `java.sql.Date` extends `java.util.Date` so a `java.sql.Date` can act as a `java.util.Date`. The main reason for using `Object` is because it meets the requirements of the API, and as the OP has stated, `Date` isn't the only type of data they want to add

Comment: @BasilBourque Probably, but I'm lazy and it means I don't need another renderer to handle `java.sql.Date` independently. Some JDBC drivers also work with `java.util.Date` (and `sql.Date`), so there's another point of cross over :P Perhaps they'll update the JDBC API to work with the new date/time API in Java 8